# Clearing multiple chips from Material-UI Autocomplete on form submission

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Form that contains several React Material Autocomplete (multi-select with Chips) components. When I submit the form the state of each Autocomplete clears properly, but visually the Chips remain shown. I can't figure out how to remove them.

I can't find any other threads discussions about this either.

**Edit:**

Code is here, it's almost unchanged from the Material-UI example:

```
<Autocomplete
    multiple
    id="tags-standard"
    options={top100Languages.map((option) => option.name)}
    onChange={(event, value) => setCategory(value)}
    freeSolo
    renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
      value.map((option, index) => (
        <Chip
          variant="outlined"
          label={option}
          {...getTagProps({ index })}
        />
      ))
    }
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} placeholder={label} />}
  />
```

and the Form is:

```
<EntryForm onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <h4>Add Entry</h4>
  <InputSelector setCategory={setThink} label={i18n("questionThink")} />
  <AddEntryLocation setLocation={setLocation} setGeolocation={setGeolocation} />
  <button>Add</button>
</EntryForm>
```

Comment: Are your autocompletes controled or not? Can you share your code parts?

Comment: updated with code

Answer (score 1):

You want to manipulate your component value from outside, that called controlled component. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vi3st) is your example.